# How To Quickly Turn Off Audio On Nexus 6P (Android 7.1.1)?

Tags: nexus

My phone is locked (pin required) and the volume is on.  I receive a text message and the appropriate sound beings to play.

How can I *very quickly* acknowledge the text message, and get the phone to shut up, but still play the audio when I receive the next text?

- Hitting volume up/volume down while the screen is locked do nothing for me.
- Hitting the power button only turns the screen on and off
- If I turn the screen on I can see the text, but if I touch it, I need to enter my pin.  Only after I successfully enter my pin will the audio stop.
- If I turn the screen on and then hit volume down, the audio will reduce in volume.  But I need to hit it many times before it gets silent.  Beyond that, the audio hasn't stopped playing, so I now need to wait for the tone to complete and then remember to turn the audio back up on the phone, or I will miss a future audio alert.

I have to imagine there is a better way.  My previous phone would simply treat the message as acknowledged with a pressing of the power button.  The best I can come up with is to replace my audio alert with a very short sound - but then I risk not hearing it/missing it.

So I want a long sound to play when I receive a text, but I want to be able to immediately acknowledge it, leaving the volume of the phone at it's current level.

I've looked in the Settings area of the phone, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Search for a notification sound on web which is short but loud enough to hear. I don't think there are options for you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting short notification sound should be the fastest way. You can also consider flashing a custom ROM based on stock android 7.1.1 which enables you to mute ringing by pressing volume button. And a lot more.

**[Video review](https://youtu.be/sV93DD-0QyQ) of AICP ROM**

[image: Screenshot]

Setting up [root and custom recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928) on Nexus 6P

[AICP ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/development/rom-aicp-official-nightlys-t3380927) 7.1.1 for Nexus 6P (officially maintained with daily builds)